# C# Client and Java Server - File Upload gets wrong Data. (sometimes)

Tags: java, c#, server, file-transfer

right now I am programming a Windows WPF Client with C# and a Server Side Application with Java. My goal is, to upload a File from the Client to the Server.

From C# I am sending the FileName (as Byte Array), the ClassNumber from the User (as Byte Array) and my File Data (as Byte Array).

I am doing it with this Code:

```
    private void SendFileDataToServer(String fileName, byte[] data)
    {

        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] klassenByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.userInfos.GetClassNumber().ToString() + ";");
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName + ";");

            stream.Write(fileNameByte, 0, fileName.Length);
            stream.Write(klassenByte, 0, klassenByte.Length);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Fehler: " + ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim übertragen der Daten!");
        }

    }
```

The Data that I am sending from C# is correct. The FileNameByteArray ends with

> 100 111 99 59

and this is Correct!
But when I get the ByteArrayData in Java, the Bytes that I get are not correct, in Java  the 4 last bytes from the FileNameByteArray looks like this:

> 100 111 59

In some Files, everything works Fine (eg. Images) but with some other Files(eg. .doc), its not working.

My Java Code looks like this:

```
    public void Server() throws IOException {
        
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
        
        System.out.println("Server wurde gestartet.");
        while(true) {
            
            System.out.println("Warte auf Clients...");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client gefunden!");
            
//          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            
            InputStream stream = client.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            
            
            while((length = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            
            byte[] data = result.toByteArray();
            
            //Dieser Part stellt sicher, dass der Dateiname
            //aus dem dataStream gelesen wird und vom Inhalt 
            //getrennt wird
            
            int counter = 0;
            boolean executeThisWhile = true;
            byte[] splitCharArr = ";".getBytes();
            byte splitChar = splitCharArr[0];
            
            ArrayList<Byte> fileNameByteArrList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            ArrayList<Byte> classNameByteArray = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            
            
            boolean fileNameIsDone = false;
            
            String x = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            
            System.out.println("x >>" + x);
            
            while (executeThisWhile) {
//              System.out.print(data[counter] + " - " + splitChar + " / ");
                if (data[counter] == splitChar || fileNameIsDone) {
                    if (data[counter] == splitChar && fileNameIsDone) {
                        executeThisWhile = false;
                    } else {
                        if (data[counter] != splitChar) {
                            classNameByteArray.add(data[counter]);                          
                        }
                    }
                    fileNameIsDone = true;
                } else {
                    fileNameByteArrList.add(data[counter]);
                }
                
                counter++;
                
            }

            byte[] newData = new byte[data.length - counter];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
                newData[i] = data[i + counter];
            }

            
            //Dateinamen rausschreiben
            byte[] fileNameByteArr = new byte[fileNameByteArrList.size()];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNameByteArrList.size(); i++) {
                fileNameByteArr[i] = fileNameByteArrList.get(i);
            }
            
            String newFileName = new String(fileNameByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            
            
            //Klassenname rausschreiben
            byte[] newClassNameByteArray= new byte[classNameByteArray.size()];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < classNameByteArray.size(); i++) {
                newClassNameByteArray[i] = classNameByteArray.get(i);
            }
            
            String newClassName = new String(newClassNameByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            char[] newClassChar = newClassName.toCharArray();
            
            newClassName = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newClassChar.length; i++) {
//              if (newClassChar[i] != ';') {
                    newClassName += newClassChar[i];                    
//              }
            }
            

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(fileNameByteArrList.size());
            System.out.println("fileme: >>" + newFileName + "<<");
            
            System.out.println("Das ist die Klasse >>" + newClassName + "<<");
            int classID = Integer.parseInt(newClassName);       
            
            System.out.println("classID: >>" + classID + "<<");

//          CreateFile(newFileName, classID, newData, pw);
                
        }
```

The Java Code is probably not the best Way to do a File download, but I didnt found another way to do this. In the Code I am getting the bytes from my C# Applicaton and I am saving it in `data`. With this dataArray, I am iteration through it and split it into my FileName, ClassNumber and the fileData. The Split Character is `;` or in decimal its `59`.

The Exception I am getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PK
O????X?
/P??I??~7$??i??J&B0Z?Du?t?OJ?K(H????xG
?L?+?v????dc????W>*??\XR?mp???Z}????HwnM?V??n???-?")/?ZwB`???4???    ??s?DX???j??"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at server.NewTestServer.Server(NewTestServer.java:148)
```

Line `148` is:

```
int classID = Integer.parseInt(newClassName);
```

So the Integer parse wont work, I assume, that the reason because this is not working is, that the variable `newClassName` has a wrong Value. And this is part of the Problem. Because the `classNumber` and the `fileName` variables doesnt have the same data as I have in C#.

My Questions here are: "How can I make my Code(the Data transfer) better?" and "How to fix the Problem, that Java gets different Data then C# sends?"

Comment: My suspicion is on somewhere in `while (executeThisWhile) {` ... I'd make that a function and unit test it. Maybe step it through. It's also more complicated, than it needs to be: Why not make that two loops?

Comment: Nice idea, I debugged it again and the byte Array (`byte[] data = result.toByteArray();`) looks a bit weird. Here are the first 100 bytes from the data byte array: https://pastebin.com/FpJkgKf0

There are a lot of `0` and `-1` maybe there could be a problem?

Comment: Ouh and not only this! in the data byte Array, its wrong too! There are again these bytes `100 49 59` but there should be these ones: `100 111 99 59`. So the `49` in the wrong part is equal to a `1` in UTF-8. So the `1` was the ClassName from the User I uploaded the File this time. Maybe there could be a problem with my Split char `;`, so that C# sends it correctly but Java understands something different, or some other issue with the transfer or with the Split Char `;`

Comment: Maybe consider changing your protocol to sending | filenamelengthinbytes | filenamebytes | classnumberlength | classnumber | data |  so you don't have to rely on separator chars. Also check for Endianness issues.

Comment: In C# Im am using `stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);` 3 times. In this Function I am already parsing the length of the byteArray, isnt my Solution the same as you suggest me to do it? Or is there some difference?

Comment: No no. I suggested to _transmit_ the length of the values to expect. So you can send "Expect 20 bytes for filename" - then you read that and parse it to int. Then you _know_ next 20 bytes will be filename. Then you send "Expect 32 bytes for classNumber" then you know next 32 bytes need to go parsed as class number an the rest is data.

Comment: @Fildor, this is pretty good idea, I'll will give it a try!

I read something about "Endianness" Issues, but in this case, there shouldnt be an Issue with it.

Comment: The length you are checking right now is the count of the bytes read. And that's correct. You should do that, because one "read" doesn't necessarily read the whole message.

Comment: "Expect 20 bytes for filename" - of course you wouldn't send that string, just an int value, of which you _know_ the exact length.

Comment: _Or_ you could go "ping-pong". For example : Client connects to server, _server_ "go ahead" (could be useful for other things ...) then you send filename, when that's received, server sends "ok, got it. Send next part". Then you send the classNumber. When that's received, server sends "Ok, got it. Send data now" - then you send the data ...

Comment: _Or_ you throw it all away and use something like gRPC ... or [(S)FTP](https://www.sftp.net/client-libraries) protocol (for which there should be implementations for either side)...

Comment: Ouh yeah, good Idea. But how can I do this? Could you please give me an Example for my case, because this is my first Data Transfer Application. Yesterday I tried to send Data back from Java to C# but I failed a few times. An Example would be pretty useful for me :).

Comment: So, I get this is "just a project to learn", right? If so, I'd suggest to start with something simpler than files. And maybe read up on different protocols and how they are implemented. Maybe start with transferring some dumb object that contains an integer, a double and some string. You'll find many interesting hiccups just in that. And many ways different protocols mitigate / solve those.

Comment: If you want to stick to file transfer, I'd start by reading into FTP for example. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/ and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959 for starters.

Comment: Well the Application is not only to learn, but at the end there should be something cool and useful at the end of the Project. The only Part on the Project thats new to me is the Data Transfering/InputString Part

Comment: I see. I see. Now, you picked a combination, that's not the most "forgiving". Transferring from .Net to .Net or Java to Java would probably be less problematic. If you want to have a platform - agnostic protocol, then your choice is not too far out, though. The hardest part is to figure out a decent protocol.

Comment: Ouh yeah the reason I picked .NET to Java was, to give it a little Challenge and to not just learn Data Transfer, but learn Data Transfer with Cross Platforms :D